# Unable to push to the local file system repository

Tags: git

I was learning git on server, and I made a git repository named it test and made two commits in it. Now I cloned this repository in /home/username named test2 by command `git clone file:///home/username/test test2` then the test2 repository as the clone of test repository is created.

Now I made a new commit in test2 repository and tried to push it to the origin by command `git push -u origin master`, now this gives the following error

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 286 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To /home/username/test/
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to '/home/username/test/'
```

Why this error occured and what to do to fix this error

Comment: I guess you did not create `/home/username/test` as a bare repository, To create a bare repository, you have to run `git init --bare` inside the folder you mean to use as remote repository (in your case `/home/username/test`). I guess you run `git init` instead

Comment: yes i do just git init

Comment: we need to do git init --bare ?, why for this case

Comment: yes, you need to make it a bare repo. Never really studied the topic, but a bare repo is used to share information between the other repos, it is used as a sort of central source of truth. You can read more: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server (officialy docs) and http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/ (for humans)

Comment: ok thanks, It helped me